# How to indent a new paragraph within items?

Tags: itemize, ieeetran

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}    
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item something
something else
\item something
something else
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And I get:

> 1) something
>
> something else
>
> 2) something
>
> something else

But, I want the new paragraph with `something else` to be indented. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enumerate` environment in `IEEEtran` accepts an optional argument with declarations for the single list. See section XI in the documentation.

The parameter to set is `\listparindent` that's initially zero.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}]
\item something something something

something else something else something else
something else something else something else

\item something

something else something else something else
something else something else something else
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also set it globally in the preamble by saying

```
\renewcommand{\IEEEiedlistdecl}{%
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
}
```

(possibly adding other settings). In this case you don't need the optional argument to `enumerate` and the indentation will be done in all such environments.

Comment: your initial: \begin{enumerate}[\listparindent=\parindent] also works.

Comment: @Elnaz Yes, but using `\setlength` is better syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumitem` package and its `listparindent=\parindent`

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=\parindent]
\item something

something else
\item something
something else
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you want it for all levels of `enumerate` put this in preamble:

```
 \setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent}
```

If you want it for only first level of `enumerate` use this:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{listparindent=\parindent}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the people at IEEE will like using `enumitem` that changes their carefully crafted redefinition of `enumerate`.

Comment: @egreg You are right. Any way this is an option for harakiri `:-)`